# preparing string to be passed to curlPerform

Tags: r

R internally saves this String

```
SOAPAction='"http://www.soaplite.com/Demo#hi"'
```

like this:

```
"\"https://hera.api.madgeniuses.net/pixiSBB/pixiWebLogin\""
```

how can i create a String like this dynamically?
I used

```
call = "Demo#hi"
SOAPAction = paste('"','http://www.soaplite.com/',call,'"',sep="")
```

**Question**
Is there a nicer way to do this? Such as a analogon to `shQuote`?

**What is this good for?**
In this tutorial of RCurl: http://www.omegahat.org/RCurl/philosophy.html

```
curlPerform(url="http://services.soaplite.com/hibye.cgi",
            httpheader=c(Accept="text/xml", Accept="multipart/*", 
            SOAPAction='"http://www.soaplite.com/Demo#hi"',
                         'Content-Type' = "text/xml; charset=utf-8"),
            postfields=body,
            verbose = TRUE
           )
```

To SOAPAction such a sting is passed. I would like to create this string dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to use `sprintf`:

```
SOAPAction <- sprintf('"http://www.soaplite.com/%s"', call)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%stri+%` operator from [stringi](http://stringi.rexamine.com) to concatenate string

```
require(stringi)
"a"%stri+%1
## [1] "a1"
```